# Can't create .env file from cloudbuild.yaml anymore(App Engine - Standard environment)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-build

Earlier(two months ago), I used to create .env file in App Engine through cloudbuild.yaml. Here is the file:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['install']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['run', 'create-env']
  env:
    - 'TYPE=${_TYPE}'
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app', 'deploy', 'app.yaml']
timeout: "1600s"
```

My package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "create-env": "printenv > .env"
  }
```

This yaml file was working as expected(creating .env file run time) earlier. I tried same file today and it did not create .env file. To cross check, I tried different name instead of .env and that worked. What's going on here? Is it no more possible?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What you can see at the App Engine logs? this could help to know what is happening.

Comment: try to replace `.env` by `/workspace/.env`

Comment: @SamuelRomero I don't see any error. Build was success! It is just not creating .env file so I can't access my environment variables using process.env. Interesting part is, in logs, it is saying that .env has been created under /workspace, but not in reality.

Comment: Since there is no logs in your App Engine or Cloud Build instances, I think the best way to know why this is happening, is contacting Google Support to take a look at it.